# "Name of project" has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, строки, динамические-массивы, heapdump

Проблема была описанна выше) Смысл программы, что бы находить самое длинное слово 1 строки, которое должно содержаться в 2 других строках. Все строки вводит пользователь.
Код программы:

```
char s1[100], s2[100], s3[100], *ptr=NULL;
int n = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
int *ch1 = new int[n];
int *ch2 = new int[b];
int *ch3 = new int[c];
char **p1 = new char*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    char *p1 = new char[n];
}
char **p2 = new char*[b];
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    char *p2 = new char[b];
}
char **p3 = new char*[c];
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    char *p3 = new char[c];
}
cout << "Enter the string: ";
gets_s(s1);
cout << "Enter the string: ";
gets_s(s2);
cout << "Enter the string: ";
gets_s(s3);
ptr = NULL;
ptr = strtok(s1, " ");
while (ptr != NULL) {
    p1[n] = ptr;
    n++;
    ch1[n] = strlen(ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
ptr = NULL;
ptr = strtok(s1, " ");
while (ptr != NULL) {
    p2[n] = ptr;
    n++;
    ch2[n] = strlen(ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
ptr = NULL;
ptr = strtok(s1, " ");
while (ptr != NULL) {
    p3[n] = ptr;
    n++;
    ch3[n] = strlen(ptr);
    ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
checker(n,b,c,p1,p2,p3,Max(ch1)); // Программа проверяет условие задания(Выделяет самое длинное слово и проверяет его на наличие в 2 остальных строках)
delete p1, p2, p3, ch1, ch2, ch3;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: И что по-вашему делает `delete p1, p2, p3, ch1, ch2, ch3;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
int *ch1 = new int[n];
int *ch2 = new int[b];
int *ch3 = new int[c];
```

Это выделение массивов длины 0.

Это тоже

```
char **p1 = new char*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    char *p1 = new char[n];
}
char **p2 = new char*[b];
for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    char *p2 = new char[b];
}
char **p3 = new char*[c];
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    char *p3 = new char[c];
}
```

Зачем вы написали эти циклы, если ни один из них заведомо не выполнится ни разу?

В массивы нулевого размера ничего нельзя записать. У вас же потом вдруг делается

```
n++;
ch1[n] = strlen(ptr);
```

т.е. очевидный выход за пределы массива. Потому программа и падает.